# Ember: model.set vs store.update

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm curious as to how `model.set('propertyName', propertyValue)` differs from `store.update('modelType', {id: 1, propertyName: propertyValue})`

Some context: In my app you click a button to run a background task, once that is completed my app will use ajax to fetch the data from the database. Once the data is updated, the component that displays the data will update and show the new data.

I tried doing the following in my controller when the background task is complete:

```
var self = this;
return Ember.$.get('someURL').done(function(data) {
    // This deserializes the data so all attribute names are camelCase
    data = deserializeData(data) 
    // At this point, data = {id: 1, attrOne: "valueOne", attrTwo: "valueTwo"}
    self.store.update('modelName', data);
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesnt trigger any updates in the view, so my component doesn't reflect the new data. In fact when I try doing `this.get('model.attrOne')`, it returns the old data for the model.

Then I tried the following:

```
var self = this;
this.store.findById('modelName', modelId).then(function(model) {
    return Ember.$.get('someURL').done(function(data) {
        // This deserializes the data so all attribute names are camelCase
        data = deserializeData(data) 
        // At this point, data = {id: 1, attrOne: "valueOne", attrTwo: "valueTwo"}
        model.setProperties(data)
    });
});
```

Now when I do this, everything works as expected, the view updates with the new data properly.

What I don't understand is why does the latter work instead and not the former?

Comment: Are you sure your id field works correctly? If so, can you maybe post a jsbin? Using store.update shouldn't definitely propagate changes. There is a starting ember-data jsbin here-> http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuxijava/1/edit

Comment: Did you mean should propogate? And I followed the ember data documentation example on the id field, though in my app I don't use integer ids but UUIDs (represented as strings) instead. But hopefully that should still work as expected. However, I was unable to recreate the error in the jsbin on first try, though I wasn't using an ember component, so let me try that after work and get back to you.